# Tool for testing/grading IPython notebook homeworks

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'll be teaching a scientific computing class with IPython notebook in the next term. Both the course content and the homework will be distributed/returned as IPython notebooks.

I remember that about half a year ago, I had stumbled across a tool designed to hand-in homework as IPython notebook. In my recollection, it had some really nice features such as

- tracking of returned homework tasks per student
- integrated grading system
- auto-testing for errors / code compliance
- unit-testing of code segments
- auto-grading features based on various metrics (e.g. speed of implementation)

Unfortunately, it seem I never saved the link - anyone seen this or any similar tool?

Answer (score 5):

Writing this question actually made me think about the right buzz-words for my web search - et voila "notebook grading system" gives https://github.com/jupyter/nbgrader right at the top (quite in contrast to "ipython notebook homework tool")!

Sorry for the noise...

Comment: Don't worry about the noise - this questions might help other people to find nbgrader. Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question!